# How can I share the data of a dictionary between two appdomains in the same process

Tags: c#, appdomain

I have a program in which I am creating two appdomains A and B . I want to share a dictionary between them. Basically I am creating the dictionary in appdomain A. At this stage, for each key in the dictionary the value part is initialized to null. Then appdomain B needs to access this dictionary and fill in the values for the corresponding keys. After this, A will use the updated dictionary. Could someone please tell me how can I go about doing this. It would be great to have a very small sample example outlining the procedure. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot share an object between two appdomains. Have a look at .net Remoting or WCF if you need to share data between two or more appdomains.

Comment: Ok, then is there a way I can pass the dictionary data between the two appdomains? Could you please provide some guidance for that

Comment: @Manan Shah: Check the following thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50153/interprocess-communication-for-windows-in-c-net-2-0

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about sharing across AppDomains but have you tried [`AppDomain.SetData()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.setdata.aspx) and [`AppDomain.GetData()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getdata.aspx)? If that doesn't work, [everyone else pretty much says use WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314268/how-best-to-communicate-between-appdomains) or if your project is older then Remoting.

Comment: Using SetData() would require you to have a reference to the appdomain, something you can only acquire in the appdomain where you spawned the "child" appdomains, so I think this wouldn´t help here.

Comment: @Chris: I did try the SetData/GetData method but it didn't work for me. When I do a GetData my dictionary count is showing zero :(

Comment: @Dominik : I do have reference to the appdomain but I am facing the problem which I mentioned above

Comment: @Manan Shah: Where do you call SetData()? I suppose you´re trying to call SetData() in domain A and then GetData in domain B, this will not work. When you start your application, your first appdomain is created without you doing anything. Then you start domains A and B. Only from the first domain you could call Setdata() on a reference to appdomain A and retrieve the data inside domain A.

Comment: @Dominik: My default domain is the Domain A. So what I am doing right now is inside domain A, I am doing B.SetData and then in the domain B, I am doing currentDomain.GetData. But I am getting the dictionary count as 0. Thanks for your help

Comment: @MananShah: What is inside your dictionary? If I remember correctly whatever you want to share using SetData has to be [Serializable]

Comment: @Dominik: My dictionary contains string, double as the key value pair

Comment: @MananShah Sorry but I have to less information to help you from here. Concerning the SetData issue I´d suggest you open a new question, although I´d recommend you´d follow the WCF approach.