# Controlling how P/Invoked assemblies are loaded into different app domains

Tags: .net, assemblies, appdomain

I've got an application which needs to call some unmanaged code in a dll. I need to do these calls from multiple app domains and specifically want the assembly to be loaded into memory multiple times (once per app domain).

I've tried doing the following:

```
    Dim AppDomainSetup As New AppDomainSetup
    With AppDomainSetup
        .PrivateBinPath = "<Blah>"
        .LoaderOptimization = LoaderOptimization.MultiDomainHost
    End With

    Dim AppDomain As AppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(String.Format("AppDomain-{0}", AppDomainCounter), Nothing, AppDomainSetup)
    AppDomainCounter += 1

    Dim Manager = CType(
        AppDomain.
        CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
            System.Reflection.Assembly.
            GetExecutingAssembly.FullName,
        "<My Manager Class>"), AppDomainManager)
    Return Manager
```

`AppDomainManager` inherits from `MarshalByRefobject` and has a method on it which (eventually) calls

```
<DllImport("<Path>",
    EntryPoint:="<MethodName>",
    CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
Private Shared Function <MethodName>(
                                    <InAttribute(),
                                    MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPStr)>
                                    ByVal sig1 As String,
                                    <InAttribute(),
                                    MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPStr)>
                                    ByVal sig2 As String) As Integer
```

However, after doing some testing, it seems that a single (instance?) of the assembly is being loaded and shared between app domains. I'd hoped that the `AppDomain.LoaderOptimization` setting would've forced a unique copy per domain.

Is there any way I can force the CLR to load the assembly multiple times?

Comment: Yes, that cannot work.  AppDomains are only meaningful to managed assemblies.  Any native DLL loaded by LoadLibrary(), the underlying call behind [DllImport], is shared by the process.  The only way to get multiple copies of the same native DLL loaded is by having multiple copies of it on disk, all with different names.  This does not scale well and should be avoided.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, the DLL in question is not thread-safe and yet I need to use it in a multi-threaded way. Is my best option to spawn multiple processes then? That seems like a lot of overhead but I don't see many alternatives. I could always automate DLL duplication but that seems like a huge kludge. Failing that, I suppose  I need to hire a C++ programmer to make it thread-safe... Also, if you want to post "You can't" as  an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: You are certainly on the wrong track with this.  The only reasonable approach is to create multiple processes, each loading its own copy of the DLL so their instance data is strictly separated.  Then use a .NET interop mechanism like WCF to get these processes to talk to your main one.

Comment: @HansPassant Would you mind reposting a summary of your comments as an answer so I can accept? I'm doing a little spring cleaning :) Many thanks

Comment: Please post your answer, showing how you solved the problem.

Comment: I went with multiple processes - so in this case, the answer is "it can't be done"/"You're approaching this wrong". If you'd prefer me to post that, I can?