# how do I make 1st app listen from 2nd app?

Tags: c#

example i want to make an app have listbox, and an custom dll which i can use on second app.

the first app is running always and listening for the second app, as soon as the dll function return value on second app , it will  return value to the 1st app  and insert the value to the lisbox.

does any one have any example how can i do it ? and what is this process called in c# ?

Thanks

Comment: There are many ways to do this, but what requirements do you have? For example, do you prefer not to use P/invoke? How fool-proof do you need it to be?

Answer (score 3):

This is called Inter-Process Communication.

[Interprocess communication for Windows in C# (.NET 2.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50153/interprocess-communication-for-windows-in-c-net-2-0)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a socket using the loopback ip address 127.0.0.1 which is easier to understand than IPC, but not reccomended for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

There are two technologies that I know of for the .NET framework. But they all boil down into inter-process communication. One is .NET Remoting and the other is [Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx). Depending on the version of the .NET framework you are using and the type of application I'd recommend using WCF.