# C# - Making a Process.Start wait until the process has start-up

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process

I need to make sure that a process is running before moving on with a method.

The statement is:

```
Process.Start("popup.exe");
```

Can you do a WAIT command or set a delay on this value?

Comment: What does "make sure" mean?  There must be a specific thing you need running in popup.exe, right?  If so, waiting for it to have run won't be enough.

Comment: Also do you have control over popup.exe?  Meaning can you add code to it to signal the spawning process that it is running?

Answer (score 151):

Do you mean wait until it's done? Then use `Process.WaitForExit`:

```
var process = new Process {
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
        FileName = "popup.exe"
    }
};
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Alternatively, if it's an application with a UI that you are waiting to enter into a message loop, you can say:

```
process.Start();
process.WaitForInputIdle();
```

Lastly, if neither of these apply, just `Thread.Sleep` for some reasonable amount of time:

```
process.Start();
Thread.Sleep(1000); // sleep for one second
```

Comment: In your first snippet, you'll have to manually call `process.Start()` before `process.WaitForExit()`; otherwise an exception will be thrown.

Comment: Just make sure you understand what WaitForInputIdle actually does http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/03/25/9984720.aspx

Comment: @ta.speot.is In other words... _Exactly_ what the OP wants?

Comment: @Basic This is a reference website, and this answer may be read by people who are not the OP.

Comment: @Eagle-Eye I'm not sure I understand your point? ta.speoit.is (neither the OP for Q or A) implied the feature didn't work as advertised. I checked the documentation and it appeared to do exactly what the OP requested. In what way was that making the site less useful for future visitors?

Comment: @Basic First off, the OP doesn't even make clear what exactly it is that they want. It's unclear if they just want the process running before moving on, if they want the process to have started accepting messages, or if they want it to have the UI ready for interaction. See this answer on another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33410894/827326

Comment: Well, the issue I am facing, which brought me here, is that I cannot call `process.BeginOutputReadLine()` or `Process.BeginErrorReadLine();` before the process was fully initialized, and so I must wait for its initialization somehow. `Thread.Sleep()` is a workaround solution, whose success may depend on the current workload of the machine. `process.WaitForInputIdle()` simply does not work if the process is not UI based, and `process.WaitForExit()` is somehow too late for me: I want to  retrieve the program's output in real time. So unfortunately nothing here worked out for me.

Answer (score 23):

I also needed this once, and I did a check on the window title of the  process. If it is the one you expect, you can be sure the application is running. The application I was checking needed some time for startup and this method worked fine for me.

```
var process = Process.Start("popup.exe");
while(process.MainWindowTitle != "Title")
{
    Thread.Sleep(10);
}
```

Comment: You may need to do `proc.Refresh();` in the loop as @AlirezaNaghizadeh mentioned

Answer (score 22):

The answer of 'ChrisG' is correct, but we need to refresh MainWindowTitle every time and it's better to check for empty.... like this:

```
var proc = Process.Start("popup.exe");
while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(proc.MainWindowTitle))
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    proc.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Can we assume  once an command-line application got a title it was started?

Comment: I added an additional check in while statement: !proc.HasExited

Answer (score 12):

First of all: I know this is rather old but there still is not an accepted answer, so perhaps my approach will help someone else. :)

What I did to solve this is:

```
process.Start();

while (true)
{
    try
    {
        var time = process.StartTime;
        break;
    }
    catch (Exception) {}
}
```

The association `var time = process.StartTime` will throw an exception as long as process did not start. So once it passes, it is safe to assume process is running and to work with it further. I am using this to wait for java process to start up, since it takes some time. This way it should be independent on what machine the application is running rather than using `Thread.Sleep()`.

I understand this is not very clean solution, but the only one that should be performance independent I could think of.

Comment: As hacky as this is, it seems like the most straightforward way to get the info needed.

Comment: Calling `process.BeginOutputReadLine()` or `Process.BeginErrorReadLine()` afterwards throws an exception which clearly states that the process has not been fully initialized yet.

Comment: That probably depends on what process you are starting. It was ok for my Java process, yours might need more time to do what it needs. But you can still use the same approach, just instead of the association call any function that is critical for you I guess. Still, hacky as hell, but should work.

Comment: Doesn't work while using with Process.Start("Excel"); This came to next line the moment it started the splash screen, but it took another 3 seconds to load the entire application.

Answer (score 7):

Like others have already said, it's not immediately obvious what you're asking.  I'm going to assume that you want to start a process and then perform another action when the process "is ready".

Of course, the "is ready" is the tricky bit.  Depending on what you're needs are, you may find that simply waiting is sufficient.  However, if you need a more robust solution, you can consider using a named [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) to control the control flow between your two processes.

For example, in your main process, you might create a named mutex and start a thread or task which will wait.  Then, you can start the 2nd process.  When that process decides that "it is ready", it can open the named mutex (you have to use the same name, of course) and signal to the first process.

Comment: That's exactly what I was expecting to find when I searched this up.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Tom.  In addition, to check the processes while performing Thread.Sleep, check the running processes. Something like:

```
bool found = 0;
while (!found)
{
    foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
        if (clsProcess.Name == Name)
            found = true;

    Thread.CurrentThread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: `while (!Process.GetProcesses().Any(p=>p.Name == myName)) { Thread.Sleep(100); }`

Comment: Why not `GetProcessesByName()`? `while(Process.GetProcessesByName(myName).Length == 0) { Thread.Sleep(100); }` While it might work most part of time, the proper way would be wait until n mileseconds and get out of loop if the process wasn't found.

Answer (score 3):

I used the [EventWaitHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.eventwaithandle?view=netframework-4.8) class. On the parent process, create a named EventWaitHandle with initial state of the event set to non-signaled. The parent process blocks until the child process calls the [Set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.eventwaithandle.set?view=netframework-4.8) method, changing the state of the event to signaled, as shown below.

Parent Process:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MyParentProcess
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EventWaitHandle ewh = null;
            try
            {
                ewh = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset, "CHILD_PROCESS_READY");

                Process process = Process.Start("MyChildProcess.exe", Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id.ToString());
                if (process != null)
                {
                    if (ewh.WaitOne(10000))
                    {
                        // Child process is ready.
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception exception)
            { }
            finally
            {
                if (ewh != null)
                    ewh.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Child Process:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MyChildProcess
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                // Representing some time consuming work.
                Thread.Sleep(5000);

                EventWaitHandle.OpenExisting("CHILD_PROCESS_READY")
                    .Set();

                Process.GetProcessById(Convert.ToInt32(args[0]))
                    .WaitForExit();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            { }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Best solution here but you need to be able to add some code in the child process.

Comment: This is the correct solution with good example code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the `Start` method returns before the child process starts? I was always under the impression that `Start` starts the child process synchronously.

If you want to wait until your child process finishes some sort of initialization then you need inter-process communication - see *[Interprocess communication for Windows in C# (.NET 2.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50153)*.

Answer (score 1):

To extend  @ChrisG's idea, a little, consider using process.MainWindowHandle and seeing if the window message loop is responding.  Use p/invoke this Win32 api: [SendMessageTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644952%28VS.85%29.aspx).
From that link:

> If the function succeeds, the return
>   value is nonzero. SendMessageTimeout
>   does not provide information about
>   individual windows timing out if
>   HWND_BROADCAST is used.
>
> If the function fails or times out, the return value is 0. To get
>   extended error information, call
>   GetLastError. If GetLastError returns
>   ERROR_TIMEOUT, then the function timed
>   out.

Answer (score 0):

Here an implementation that uses a `System.Threading.Timer`. Maybe a bit much for its purpose.

```
    private static bool StartProcess(string filePath, string processName)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unknown filepath: {(string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath) ? "EMPTY PATH" : filePath)}");

        var isRunning = false;

        using (var resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false))
        {

            void Callback(object state)
            {
                if (!IsProcessActive(processName)) return;
                isRunning = true;
                // ReSharper disable once AccessToDisposedClosure
                resetEvent.Set();
            }

            using (new Timer(Callback, null, 0, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5).Milliseconds))
            {
                Process.Start(filePath);
                WaitHandle.WaitAny(new WaitHandle[] { resetEvent }, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(9));
            }
        }

        return isRunning;
    }

    private static bool StopProcess(string processName)
    {
        if (!IsProcessActive(processName)) return true;

        var isRunning = true;

        using (var resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false))
        {

            void Callback(object state)
            {
                if (IsProcessActive(processName)) return;
                isRunning = false;
                // ReSharper disable once AccessToDisposedClosure
                resetEvent.Set();
            }

            using (new Timer(Callback, null, 0, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5).Milliseconds))
            {
                foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName(processName))
                    process.Kill();
                WaitHandle.WaitAny(new WaitHandle[] { resetEvent }, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(9));
            }
        }

        return isRunning;
    }

    private static bool IsProcessActive(string processName)
    {
        return Process.GetProcessesByName(processName).Any();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class WinApi
{

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    public static class Windows
    {
        public const int NORMAL = 1;
        public const int HIDE = 0;
        public const int RESTORE = 9;
        public const int SHOW = 5;
        public const int MAXIMIXED = 3;
    }

}
```

App

```
String process_name = "notepad"
Process process;
process = Process.Start( process_name );

while (!WinApi.ShowWindow(process.MainWindowHandle, WinApi.Windows.NORMAL))
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    process.Refresh();
}

// Done!
// Continue your code here ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working for command line processes...

Comment: @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp Of course it doesn't work for non-interface processes, they do not have MainWindowHandle.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check if the started process is responsive or not by trying something like this:
while(process.responding)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using these two methods:

```
    public static void WaitUntilLoad(Process process, int? millisecond = null)
    {
        while ((!millisecond.HasValue || millisecond > 0) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            if (millisecond.HasValue) millisecond -= 100;
            process.Refresh();
        }
    }
    public static void WaitUntilExit(Process process, int? millisecond = null)
    {
        if (millisecond.HasValue) process.WaitForExit(millisecond.Value);
        else process.WaitForExit();
    }
```

Enjoy...

Answer (score 0):

I think Tom was looking for something like this:

```
Process process = Process.Start(@"MyApp.exe");
Process[] processes;

do
{
    processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("MyApp");
    Console.WriteLine("{0} Processes found.", processes.Length);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
while (processes.Length == 0);

Close(); // Or do whatever you want...
```