# Wait on a process in a task

Tags: c#, winapi, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to do the following :
I have a window with a grid, and in each cell I want to display a distant computer (using VNC). To do so, I start processes and put them in panels.

My problem is that I have to wait for that process to be a certain window (because an authentication window get displayed for a short time before the real window that I want).

So for each process I have to start I do this :

```
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Process proc = Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\RealVNC\VNC4\vncviewer.exe", name + " -Scaling AspectFit -Enabletoolbar=0");
    Thread.Sleep(4000); // Wait for real window
    this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
         AddProcessToTable(proc, name); // Adds the window in the panel
    });
});
```

And it works fine ; but if I want to replace the `Thread.Sleep()` with this :

```
while (!proc.MainWindowTitle.Contains(name))
    Thread.Sleep(10);
```

but when I do so, my processes are started but they don't go in the panels. I put breakpoint to check, and the lines in the while and after the while are executed, so I don't know where it could go wrong...
It must be possible since [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6390261/860246) did it.

FYI, here is the function adding the processes to the TableLayoutPanel :

```
void AddProcessToTable(Process proc, string name)
{
    Control panel = null;
    // ...
    // Retrieving panel
    // ...

    SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, panel.Handle);
    SendMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, 274, 61488, 0);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if linking the window hierarchy across processes and threads is such a good idea.

Comment: Yes I was also thinking mixing winapi and tasks sounds like trouble, but it considerably speed up the overall processing when it works (with the Thread.Sleep). I would just like to make it depend less on the Thread.Sleep, and I don't know why there is a behaviour difference between my two solutions

Answer (score 0):

instead of Thread.Sleep, why not use proc.WaitForInputIdle(), which will wait for the process to enter the its main window's message loop and be ready for input.  There's the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d7363e2.aspx, and I found (but didnt test) an article on how to use it at http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_process_handling.html

```
Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "Notepad";
    process.Start();

    process.WaitForInputIdle();

    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    if(!process.CloseMainWindow())
    {
        process.Kill();
    }
```

Comment: I don't think waiting for input is the right thing, because the first window I'm trying to avoid capturing does have input, for login and password. But I still gave it a try and had the same problem, my processes were launched but not put in the panels.