# run multiple shell commands one by one in c#

Tags: c#, shell, cmd, command, dos

I want to run multiple shell commands from c#. I've tried `Process.Start("");` but it opens new instances for each command. I've also tried `ProcessStartInfo` with `StreamWriter` [(ref.)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/437444/1160207) but it doesn't work for me. I want to exeute following shell commands from my c# application.

```
timeout 10
taskkill /F /IM "v*"
taskkill /F /IM "B*"
timeout 5
shutdown /f /p
```

How can I run these commands one by one from my c# application?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390030/c-sharp-making-a-process-start-wait-until-the-process-has-start-up) may provide some helpful answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `Process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow` and `Process.WaitForExit()`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx

You can also eliminate the "timeout" commands by doing `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)`

Here is some code to get you started:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
    ExecuteCommandAndWait("taskkill", "/F /IM \"v*\"");
    ExecuteCommandAndWait("taskkill","/F /IM \"B*\"");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    ExecuteCommandAndWait("shutdown", "/f /p");
}

private static void ExecuteCommandAndWait(string fileName, string arguments)
{
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating CMD file and running it is probably the easiest option.

Side note: `shutdown /f /t 30` maybe an easier command.