# How to run Two process one after another using C#?

Tags: c#, process

I have a application which will open a two microsoft ppsx file one after another. for that i have used process object to run the files. mention bellow

```
Process process = Process.Start(@"E:\test\test.ppsx");
```

I need to run the files in such a way that after finishing the first file ,second file should run automatically. can some one suggest me how can achieve that.

Comment: You can try using Process.WaitForExit()

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390030/c-sharp-making-a-process-start-wait-until-the-process-has-start-up

Comment: Are you telling that after opening the first file you want to open another ? Not after closing the first file opening other

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `WaitForExit` method to wait to end process (Something like this):

```
var process1 = Process.Start(...);
process1.WaitForExit();

var process2 = Process.Start(...);
```

or subscribe into a `Process.Exited` event and execute another process after the first one. Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx) for your reference.

Comment: This is working fine. but I need when the second process will start first process should stop or close. is it possible?

Comment: I have two files. I want to run that two files consecutively one after another, according to your suggestion it is running. but I want to stop the first process to start the second one.

Comment: yes, that I want to know the time taken by the first process. and after that time the second one will open

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Process.WaitForExit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx) method.

> Instructs the Process component to wait indefinitely for the
>   associated process to exit.

Also check [`Process.Exited`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx) event.

> Occurs when a process exits.

```
Process process = Process.Start(@"E:\test\test.ppsx");
process.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Process.WaitForExit()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Process.Start(@"c:\temp\presentation1.pptx").WaitForExit();
        }).ContinueWith(o => 
        {
            Process.Start(@"c:\temp\presentation2.pptx").WaitForExit();
        });
        Console.ReadKey();
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get all the ppsx files from the test directory in the E drive in an array and process on the array of ppsx files according to your requirements.

```
 string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("your path");
```

loop through the array and pass each file path to the Process constructor and as lexeRoy said you can WaitForExit.