# Show message while process (outlook) starts

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I have this:

```
var proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = $"mailto:webmaster@mydomain.com? ... .";
proc.Start();
```

Starting outlook takes some time during which it is not clear anything happens.
How can I show a message, saying Outlook is started, which message disappears when outlook comes up?
I hope there is some event, I can monitor, that happens when outlook shows up...?

Comment: You can try to use Outlook interop to create Outlook application, create and send e-mail. I am not sure if it still supported for the latest versions of Outlook. Your idea in general assumes that the user uses Outlook, while `mailto` protocol can be bound to any other app.

Comment: As I know, there is no flag indicating that a process a ended its startup unless you code that in your app, but you can Start and WaitForExit. A simple manner is to create a Form, to show it before start process and to destroy it after in case it is possible : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390030/c-sharp-making-a-process-start-wait-until-the-process-has-start-up