# How do I wait for an Explorer window to finish opening?

Tags: c#, windows, explorer, process.start

Full repro example (.NET Framework 4.8 Console application, Windows 10):

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var p = Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"C:\Windows");
        p.WaitForInputIdle();
        // Thread.Sleep(5000);
        MessageBox.Show("Explorer window has opened.");
    }
}
```

**Actual behavior**: The message box shows up. A few seconds later, the Explorer window opens in front of the message box, thereby hiding the message.

**Desired behavior**: The code waits until the Explorer window is visible (that's what I expected `WaitForInputIdle` to do) and then shows the message box in front of the Explorer window.

**What I've already tried**:

- If I activate the `Thread.Sleep` statement in my code example, it works (i.e., I get the desired behavior). I don't like that solution, because the time it takes to open the Explorer window
  might be different on my computer and on my customers' computers.
- I tried various combinations of the various `ProcessStartInfo` options (`UseShellExecute`, `WindowStyle`, `CreateNoWindow`), but it did not make a difference. Note that **I don't want to hide the Explorer window**, I just want to wait until it's visible.
- I know that I can use `SetForegroundWindow` to make my process the foremost window. That doesn't help. It's (a) apparently not necessary (the Thread-Sleep-variant works without it) and (b) I'd need to do it *after* the Explorer window finished opening to prevent the Explorer window from "stealing" the foreground again, leading back to my original problem.
- I also tried checking `p.MainWindowTitle` in a loop, but that value stays empty even after the window has opened (or the process exits). Apparently, the new Explorer window is *actually* owned by a different process than the one I started.
- I know that I could use the Windows API methods `FindWindow` or `EnumWindows` to find out if *any* window with the name of the folder exists, but that's (a) a lot of work and (b) not very elegant.

Did I miss an obvious, correct solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a solution to your problem here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35789386/18486478.

I also find it cleaner to use the `Responding` variable.

```
var p = Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"C:\Windows");
while (!p.Responding)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1);
    p.Refresh();
}
p.WaitForInputIdle();
MessageBox.Show("Explorer window has opened.");
```

Comment: Except this doesn't work for the immediately-exiting Explorer.exe.

Comment: Indeed, I tried using it with another program but the behaviour of exporer.exe is different. I can't access the process after it was started so the best bet is to find how to get the new process created.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you have to use the not very elegant way.

If you try:

```
var p = Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"C:\Windows");
p.WaitForExit();
MessageBox.Show("Explorer window has opened.");
```

You will find the message box still shows, this means the window you saw doesn't belong to the process you created. There is a default explorer process when Windows starts, the new explorer process seems to like looking for the default one and let it create a new window. There is an option called "Launch folder windows in a separate process", unfortunately, after my test, this option does not work now.